# Is there a tool to view and edit ,iso files like PowerISO?

Tags: mount, iso, file-manager

I am looking for a archive manager that will allow me to look into the contents without needing to mount it and also to add or remove contents by drag and drop style. The Windows' equivalent would be PowerISO, MagicISO or even 7-zip.

Many people suggested mounting and then copying into another directory, add/remove files, and make image again. Is that the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `isomaster`, althrough it lacks the support of non ascii characters

Comment: Does some of the job, but not all. Some bootup disc can't be edited this way. I have to do it through virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

Try [WinRAR](http://www.win-rar.com/download.html?&L=0). It has done the trick for me in Windows and there is a Linux version as well.

Comment: This is too difficult for me. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: I mean i don't know how to install it. Followed the instructions in makefile and don't know what's next.